# Finding the basis of all vectors perpendicular to one vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let **v** = $\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        2 \\
        3 \\
        4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ in $\mathbb R^4$.

How I can find a basis of the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ such that the subspace consists of all vectors perpindicular to **v**.

I know how to find three vectors, but I can't explain why. I know $a+2b+3c+4d=0$ for any vector in the subspace if $a, b, c, d$ are coefficients of the vector. How would I go about using this fact to prove that the vectors I use are the basis of the subspace?

This is the basis I've found using the dot product formula:
$\begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
        3 \\
        0 \\
        -1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}
        4 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$. How can I go about explaining this?

Comment: Just verify that your three vectors are linearly independent, and you're done. Set a linear combination of them equal to $0$, and verify that all coefficients must be $0$.

Comment: Yeah, I know their linearly independent by the zeroes, but how does that show they are the basis of the subspace that contains all vectors perpendicular to v?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, you said you know that $a + 2b + 3c + 4d = 0$ for any vector perpendicular to $\mathbf{v}$. This is the equation defining a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$; a subspace of codimension $1$, that is, a $3$-dimensional subspace. You've found three linearly independent vectors in that $3$-dimensional subspace, so it must be a basis.

Comment: How many vectors do you need in this vector space to have a basis?

Comment: Oh I see. dim(v)+dim(v(perp))=4.Therefore, as dim(v)=1, dim(v(perp))=3, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly found a basis for the subspace.  In most classes, your answer would be fine and you could stop there.

We could prove (if you wanted to) that your set is a basis as follows:

First, note that your set of vectors is indeed linearly independent.  Next, note that if we added a fourth linearly independent vector, we'd have a basis for $\Bbb R^4$, which would imply that *every* vector is perpendicular to $(1,2,3,4)$, which is clearly not true.

So, you have a the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in your space.  This must, then, be a basis for the space, as desired.